# Saving python plot with background transparency .tif

Tags: python, matplotlib, transparent

I want to save plots I made with python as tif files with a transparent background. When I just make one plot and save it, than I have no problem, i.e. I get a graph with transparent background. However, when I want to save a subplot, than suddenly it ignores the transparency argument.

Here is part of the code I'm using for the subplots:

```
plt.clf()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
ax2=fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')

(plotting data)    

name2=path+name+'.tif'
plt.savefig(name2, bbox_inches='tight',dpi=1000,transparency=True)
```

path contains the path to the folder I want to save the file in. name is the name of the figure.

So my question is: Why doesn't the transparency argument work for subplots? I did check whether this problem is known, but I have not found another post that discussed this problem ...

Comment: For me, also the a single plot is not transparent after saving to tif

Answer (score 0):

For subplots to be transparent you need to change background of each subplot:

```
ax.patch.set_color('none')
```

Note that `'none'` should be a string.

Alternatively you can change alpha level:

```
ax.patch.set_alpha(0)
```

Either way will produce the same result.

Comment: Somehow that does not work for me. I'm using Python 2.7 (python x/y), should it also work in this version of python?

Comment: You may want to include a small reproducible example to illustrate the problem.